# gRPC - Node Js - How to send request from client to server with different port?

Tags: javascript, grpc, grpc-node

I'm a new in gRPC. I code my app with gRPC. It's working good with client and server in same port. Now, I want to set up the client port differently from the port on the server. I'm find many hours this problem in Google but I cant find it. What can I do.

My server code:

```
const grpc = require('grpc')

const protoLoader = require('@grpc/proto-loader')
const packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync('notes.proto');
const notesProto = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition);

const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1')

const server = new grpc.Server()
const notes = [
    { id: '1', title: 'Note 1', content: 'Content 1'},
    { id: '2', title: 'Note 2', content: 'Content 2'}
]

server.addService(notesProto.NoteService.service, {
  ...
})

server.bind('127.0.0.1:50051',
  grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure())
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:50051')
server.start()
```

My client code:

```
const PROTO_PATH = '../notes.proto';

const grpc = require('grpc');
const protoLoader = require('@grpc/proto-loader')
const packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(PROTO_PATH);
const NoteService = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition).NoteService

const client = new NoteService('localhost:50052',  // <- problem here
    grpc.credentials.createInsecure());

module.exports = client
```

Answer (score 0):

The client does not have its own port. That address gives the port number where the client will attempt to connect to a server. The two numbers need to match or the client will be unable to find the server.